# No Value being returned in Django Post Request in the QueryDict

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to learn Django and can't find a solution anywhere.  I run a submit button to gather a fullname, but when I hit submit, it shows None as the value.  I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  It was missing the csrf token, but I added that and it still comes back with none.

[image: My Result for QueryDict]

**view.html**

```html
       <div class='containter'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col'>
                <p>{{ content }}</p>
<div class='col-sm-6 col-12'>

<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder="Name" value='fullname'>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>

</form>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home_page(request):
    context = {
        "title": "Homepage",
        "content": "Welcome to the Homepage"
    }
    return render(request, "home_page.html", context)

def about_page(request):
    context = {
        "title": "About Page",
        "content": "Welcome to the About Page"
        }
    return render(request, "home_page.html", context)

def contact_page(request):
    context = {
        "title": "Contact Us",
        "content": "Welcome to the Contact Page"
        }
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        print(request.POST.get('fullname'))
    return render(request, "contact/view.html", context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import home_page, about_page, contact_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_page),
    url(r'^about/$', about_page),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact_page),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem that you have in your code is that you are not sending a input called 'fullname', you actually are sending an input without name, with value 'fullname'.

you have to update the HTML and set the name atribbute in the input tag:

```
<input type='text' name='fullname' value='what ever you need to get in backend'>
```

so, in backend you can get the value of the input:

```
request.POST.get('fullname')
```

and this will get the next string: `what ever you need to get in backend`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder="Name" value='fullname'>
```

should be something like

```
<input type='text' class='form-control'  name="fullname" placeholder="Name" value='fullname'>
```